# Entity Framework Core Dependency Conflict involving JSON.NET

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure WebJobs console app which needs to access a database built around Entity Framework Core 1.0. I'm running into a dependency conflict warning when the console app runs.

Apparently, WebJobs utilizes v6 of JSON.NET but EF Core requires v9, I think because of the IOptions based configuration capability of EF Core.

Is it okay to ignore this type of warning? I have to use a ConfigurationManager-based approach to configuring the console app anyway, because WebJobs doesn't understand the type of config file approach used by ASPNET Core. So I don't >>think<< the conflict will ever amount to anything.

But I'm out of my depth and would appreciate some expert feedback.

Answer (score 0):

At currently, I would suggest you use Console Application core to create your webjob. The Azure Webjob template currently based on .Net Framework. Maybe will have some issues when use EF core in it. [Here](https://github.com/devkimchi/.NET-Core-for-Azure-WebJob-Sample) is a .NET Core for Azure WebJob Sample. For how to let Azure WebJobs with .NET Core RC2, please refer to [this article](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/06/08/azure-webjobs-with-dotnet-core-rc2/).